# Cannot send messages using fbchat on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-python-api

```
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat.models import *

client = Client('<username>', '<password>')

print('Own id: {}'.format(client.uid))

client.send(Message(text='Hi me!'), thread_id='clientname', thread_type=ThreadType.USER)

client.logout()
```

The code sample above is what I got from a tutorial online, the program is able to login to Facebook messenger and tell me my user id. Then I added in a client.send to see if it actually sends a message using facebook messenger to one of my contacts but then i get this in IDLE. Can anybody provide solutions for this issue?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/fbchat trial.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.send(Message(text='Hi me!'), thread_id='User', thread_type=ThreadType.USER)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fbchat\client.py", line 955, in send
    return self._doSendRequest(data)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fbchat\client.py", line 923, in _doSendRequest
    j = self._post(self.req_url.SEND, data, fix_request=True, as_json=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fbchat\client.py", line 128, in _post
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fbchat\client.py", line 124, in _post
    return check_request(r, as_json=as_json)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fbchat\utils.py", line 193, in check_request
    raise FBchatFacebookError('Error when sending request: Got {} response'.format(r.status_code), request_status_code=r.status_code)
fbchat.models.FBchatFacebookError: Error when sending request: Got 500 response
```

Comment: change the thread_id value to `client.uid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to try this. I think your thread_id is wrong.

```
client.send(Message(text='Hi me!'), thread_id=client.uid, thread_type=ThreadType.USER)
```

Comment: so if i want to send a message to another person i would change client.uid to the clients id??

Comment: @RS That's correct. This program will send a message to yourself :D. Unless talking to yourself is what you want?